# Database date and jquery date validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datepicker

My database has the following table

```
event_id                           event_name               event_date
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                                  Training on C/C++        02-11-2015           
2                                  Core Java                03-11-2015
3                                  Advanced Java            04-11-2015
4                                  Cloud Computing          09-11-2015
5                                  Cloud Computing          10-11-2015
6                                  Big Data                 12-11-2015
```

The dates are simply as strings i.e. the event_date column is of type varchar. I need to check if the date selected from the jQuery datepicker matches with at least one of the dates in the `event_date` column. For any other date selected,apart from 02-11-2015, the `alert` in `else` gets popped up. When I run it, only the first date gets correctly validated. Is there a problem with the loop? How do I solve this problem?

```tml
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"   
        });
        $('form#dateform').submit(function(){   
            var aselectedDate = $('#datepicker').val();
            localStorage.setItem('adate', aselectedDate);
        });
    });
</script>

<?php
    $adateStringValue = (isset($_POST['datepicker'])) ? $_POST['datepicker'] : '';
    echo '<form id="dateform" name="dateform" action="" method="POST"><br><br>
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <td><b>Select a date &nbsp;&nbsp;<b></td>
                  <td><input id="datepicker" name="datepicker" size="15" value="' .$adateStringValue . '"/></td>
              </tr>
          </table>
          <br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>';

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {    
        $sql1 = "SELECT event_date from events_schedule";
        $getDates_query = mysql_query($sql1, $con);
        $fetchdates = mysql_fetch_array($getDates_query);

        while ($fetchdates = mysql_fetch_array($getDates_query)) 
        {
            if ($fetchdates['event_date'] == $adateStringValue) 
            {
                $message = "You have selected this date for your training: $adateStringValue";
                echo "<script>alert('$message');</script>";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                $message1 = "No Training Event is scheduled on this date. Please select another date";
                echo "<script>alert('$message1');</script>";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

So.. ..you are getting all the dates from the DB.. ..and looping through them all each time, popping up a JS alert box for each row.

Why not use the date from the date picker in the query.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM events_schedule WHERE event_date='$adateStringValue'";
```

The deal with the response wether or not it returns a record.

..just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If i am getting what you want, you can make use of [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function. It converts datetime string passed to it to Unix timestamp which you can use for comparison.

If date from datepicker is **02-11-2015** then the function will return **1446422400** and if the date stored in db is **02-11-2015** then also the function will return **1446422400** so you can comapre the two easiyl.

```
$var1 = strtotime($adateStringValue);

$var2 = strtotime($fetchdates['event_date']);
```

Then comparison can be made as `if($var1 == $var2)`

**Note:** It is just an example and explanation of function usage. You will have to make modifications as per your need.

Comment: Thank you.. But this still did not solve the problem. It works only for this date 03-11-2015.